# constantly consuming high CPU

Tags: performance

i want to use software to monitor my network, the monitor process is consuming 20% CPU times, is it any impact to my device except battery life?

If a program constantly consume high CPU, will it create a lot of heat and ruin the device ?

Answer (score 1):

Constant battery use will generate more heat over a short period of time, yes.  Ordinarily, this will not damage the device.  However, heat can greatly impact the longevity of your battery.  I would suggest shutting off the monitor when you don't need it; if you really need to constantly monitor the network, the task is probably better suited to a PC.

Answer (score 1):

The 20% CPU consumption is *probably* because you are on a weaker CPU, eg, 528 Mhz processors , in this case, the CPU consumption is normal anyway and as a matter of fact, 20% is not a high number in this case at all.

In case you want to limit your CPU usage at all times, you can root your device, install a CPU scaling program , and *under clock* the device. Or you can set the CPU governor to "powersave" in addition to under clocking the CPU frequency if you want to sacrifice the performance for a longer battery life.