# /system/xbin/sh high cpu usage

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, motorola-droid-razr, processes, processor

I'm using OS Monitor to look at CPU usage because I've noticed a drastic performance decrease lately. The app shows that `system/xbin/sh` is consuming anywhere from 10% to 70% of the CPU. This happens constantly, the process never stops appearing at the top of the list. I have a two questions:

1. What is `system/xbin/sh`?
2. What could be causing it to utilize so much of the CPU?
3. Is there a way to track which apps make calls to `system/xbin/sh`?

More Info:

- Android version: 4.1.2
- Phone: Motorola DROID RAZR MAXX HD
- ROM: Droid Nexesque v3.8 (AOSP-based ROM) (through safestrap)
- Rooted: yes
- not running any anti-virus or the like

`adb shell top` output:

```
PID PR CPU% S  #THR     VSS     RSS PCY UID      Name
6214  0  97% R     1 182528K  92452K     root     /system/xbin/sh
...
6211  0   0% S     1   1428K    448K     root     /system/xbin/sh
6212  0   0% S     1  53500K  52596K     root     /system/xbin/sh    
...
```

`adb shell ps` output:

```
USER     PID   PPID  VSIZE  RSS     WCHAN    PC         NAME
root      1     0     544    404   ffffffff 00000000 S /init
...
root      6211  1     1428   448   ffffffff 00000000 S /system/xbin/sh
root      6212  6211  53500  52596 ffffffff 00000000 S /system/xbin/sh
root      6214  6212  293976 214156 ffffffff 00000000 R /system/xbin/sh
...
```

`cat /proc/<pid>/cmdline` output:

```
"level 1" process: /system/xbin/sh /system/bin/debuggerd
"level 2" process: /system/xbin/sh /system/etc/init.d.loader
"level 3" process: /system/xbin/sh /system/etc/init.d.loader
```

`/system/etc/init.d.loader` contents:

```
#!/system/xbin/sh
############# ############# #############
# init.d.loader by puppet13th@xda
# Version 0.7 19 June 2012
# to run script in background append .bgrun to script name
# example : "myscript.bgrun"
# ############# ############# #############
logfile=/data/init.d.loader.log
loglength=65536
bgrunsign='.bgrun'
if [ -f $logfile ]
    then
    log=`cat $logfile`
    currentloglength=`length "$log"`
    if [ $currentloglength -gt $loglength ]
    then
    rm -f $logfile  fi
fi
echo " * `date` * init.d.loader start . . .">>$logfile
echo " ">>$logfile
if [ ! -d /system/etc/init.d ]
    then
    echo "  creating init.d folder . . .">>$logfile
    mount -o remount rw /system >>$logfile 2>>$logfile
    if [ -f /system/etc/init.d ]
        then
        rm -f /system/etc/init.d >>$logfile 2>>$logfile
    fi
    mkdir /system/etc/init.d >>$logfile 2>>$logfile
mount -o remount ro /system >>$logfile 2>>$logfile
fi
echo " ">>$logfile
echo " i : running init.d scripts . . .">>$logfile
for script in /system/etc/init.d/*
do
    if [ -x $script ]
    then
    bgrun=`grep $bgrunsign $script`>/dev/null
        if [ $? = 0 ]
        then
        echo "  - running $script in background . . .">>$logfile
        /system/xbin/sh $script & >>$logfile 2>>$logfile
        else
        echo "  - running $script . . .">>$logfile
        /system/xbin/sh $script>>$logfile 2>>$logfile
        fi
    fi
done
echo " ">>$logfile
echo " * `date` * init.d.loader end . . .">>$logfile
echo " ">>$logfile
```

`/system/bin/debuggerd` contents:

```
#!/system/xbin/sh
#init.d.loader
/system/etc/init.d.loader
/system/bin/debuggerd.bin
```

Checking `/data/local` for things other tools might have left to "plug into `init`": There are four empty folders and a file named `RootToolsMounts`. `/data/local/RootToolsMounts` contents:

```
rootfs / rootfs ro,relatime 0 0
tmpfs /dev tmpfs rw,nosuid,relatime,mode=755 0 0
devpts /dev/pts devpts rw,relatime,mode=600 0 0
proc /proc proc rw,relatime 0 0
sysfs /sys sysfs rw,relatime 0 0
none /acct cgroup rw,relatime,cpuacct 0 0
tmpfs /mnt/asec tmpfs rw,relatime,mode=755,gid=1000 0 0
tmpfs /mnt/obb tmpfs rw,relatime,mode=755,gid=1000 0 0
none /dev/cpuctl cgroup rw,relatime,cpu 0 0
tmpfs /dev tmpfs rw,nosuid,relatime,mode=755 0 0
devpts /dev/pts devpts rw,relatime,mode=600 0 0
/dev/block/platform/msm_sdcc.1/by-name/userdataorig /datamedia ext4 rw,relatime,user_xattr,barrier=1,data=ordered 0 0
/dev/block/platform/msm_sdcc.1/by-name/userdataorig /ss ext4 rw,relatime,user_xattr,barrier=1,data=ordered 0 0
tmpfs /mnt/asec tmpfs rw,relatime,mode=755,gid=1000 0 0
tmpfs /mnt/obb tmpfs rw,relatime,mode=755,gid=1000 0 0
none /dev/cpuctl cgroup rw,relatime,cpu 0 0
/dev/block/platform/msm_sdcc.1/by-name/system /system ext4 ro,relatime,user_xattr,barrier=1,data=ordered 0 0
/dev/block/platform/msm_sdcc.1/by-name/userdata /data ext4 rw,nosuid,nodev,noatime,nodiratime,user_xattr,barrier=0,data=ordered,noauto_da_alloc,discard 0 0
/dev/block/platform/msm_sdcc.1/by-name/cache /cache ext4 rw,nosuid,nodev,noatime,nodiratime,user_xattr,barrier=1,data=ordered 0 0
/dev/block/platform/msm_sdcc.1/by-name/persist /persist ext4 rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_xattr,barrier=1,data=ordered 0 0
/dev/block/platform/msm_sdcc.1/by-name/modem /firmware ext4 ro,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_xattr,barrier=1,data=ordered 0 0
/dev/block/platform/msm_sdcc.1/by-name/pds /pds ext3 rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,barrier=0,data=writeback 0 0
/dev/fuse /storage/sdcard0 fuse rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=1023,group_id=1023,default_permissions,allow_other 0 0
/dev/block/vold/179:97 /storage/sdcard1 vfat rw,dirsync,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,uid=1000,gid=1015,fmask=0702,dmask=0702,allow_utime=0020,codepage=cp437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,utf8,errors=remount-ro 0 0
```

Looking at `/data/init.d.loader.log` (~50 MB file), it is running the `init.d` scripts approximately every  10 seconds. I'm not too familiar with the underlying components of Android, so I'm not sure if this is a lot or not. The two scripts in `/system/etc/init.d./` are `init.d.loader.test` and `minfree`.

`/data/init.d.loader.log` contents:

The log file is filled with these entries repeating every 10-12 seconds

```
...
* Sun Feb 23 18:46:09 CST 2014 * init.d.loader
start...
i: running init.d scripts...
 - running /system/etc/init.d/init.d.loader.test...
 - running /system/etc/init.d/minfree...
* Sun Feb 23 18:46:09 CST 2014 * init.d.loader
end...
* Sun Feb 23 18:46:20 CST 2014 * init.d.loader
start...
i: running init.d scripts...
 - running /system/etc/init.d/init.d.loader.test...
 - running /system/etc/init.d/minfree...
* Sun Feb 23 18:46:20 CST 2014 * init.d.loader
end...
...
```

`init.d.loader.test` contents:

```
#!/system/xbin/sh
# init.d.loader tester
# check /data/init.d.loader.test
echo init.d.loader test >/data/init.d.loader.test
```

`minfree` contents:

```
#!/system/xbin/sh
echo "2469,4938,6584,33756,36971,40186" > /sys/module/lowmemorykiller/parameters/minfree
```

Comment: PS: Have you read [this](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/6451/constantly-consuming-high-cpu?rq=1)

Comment: @t0mm13b I have read that, but that wouldn't seem to help my problem. I added the `ps` and `top` outputs for `/system/xbin/sh`. I'm not sure if this will help. If this doesn't help, I'm probably just going to wipe the ROM and start over. It will be easier than narrowing it down app by app.

Comment: It seems like this script is getting into infinite loop or something like that. Can you check the content of the scripts's log file: /data/init.d.loader.log and observe it over the next five minutes whether or not the log file is changing or being written to.

Comment: For what the script is supposed to do, it should only run once at boot IMHO. Btw: the `/data/local/RootToolsMounts` looks like a form of `fstab` to me (but is definitely not causing the trouble here).

Comment: @StrangerLoop: Does your ROM comes with busybox, if it does can you use the `tail <filename>` command to check the show the last few lines in the log file, about fifteen lines should suffice for now. Tail command: `tail -n 15 /data/init.d.loader.log`

Comment: From the script, that looks very suspicious, if I were you OP, I'd chase up the guy over on XDA (**puppet13th@xda**) and find out exactly why is it looping over all scripts in `etc` directory, remounting the system as rewriteable without your knowledge and executing them in the background. My conclusion from reading the above is, this is a bogus script as part of maybe, a rooting process, that slipped through, looking at `/proc/pid/cmdline`, level 2 is of concern, `inti.d.loader` (was this pasted in or a typo?) That is unheard of.

Comment: @t0mm13b Definitely a typo, it should read `init.d.loader`. I have contacted the developer of the ROM on droidrzr.com (the thread on that site is the one that is updated by the developer). I will also try to get a hold of puppet13th on xda.

Comment: Glad that its a typo then so... :)

Comment: My current guess is that the script took a lot of CPU time because it uses a very inefficient way of calculating the log file length, which is to read the entire log file to memory and use `length`. This shouldn't have been much of an issue if the log file is small, but since you said that log file's current size is more than 50MB, this shows that the log file isn't getting trimmed properly. Another concerning issue is that init scripts are supposed to only run once at startup, but this script is obviously being run periodically.

Comment: If my guess is correct, you may be able to fix this temporarily by deleting the log file, but eventually the slow down will occur again when the log file is filled again. Check if you have the latest version of your ROM, maybe it's fixed in the latest version? Otherwise if it's an unmaintained ROM, you'll need to figure out a way to fix the script.

Comment: @LieRyan You were correct! That fixed the problem for now, but as you said, over time it's going to reappear. I am on the latest version of the ROM, unfortunately. I will get in contact with the ROM dev and the dev that wrote `init.d.loader`. Thanks for everyone's help. I appreciate it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My current guess is that the script took a lot of CPU time because it uses a very inefficient way of calculating the log file length, which is to read the entire log file to memory and use `length`. This shouldn't have been much of an issue if the log file is small, but since you said that log file's current size is more than 50MB, this shows that the log file isn't getting trimmed properly. Another concerning issue is that init scripts are supposed to only run once at startup, but this script is obviously being run periodically.

If my guess is correct, you may be able to fix this temporarily by deleting the log file, but eventually the slow down will occur again when the log file is filled again. Check if you have the latest version of your ROM, maybe it's fixed in the latest version? Otherwise if it's an unmaintained ROM, you'll need to figure out a way to fix the script.

Answer (score -1):

I'm only **GUESSING**  but have you tried lowering the log Buffer size? **Feature is listed in Dev Options** *`>Settings>Developer Options>Logger Buffer Size`*

Comment: Community wiki isn't for answers like this, it's for "canonical" answers that the whole community should contribute to.